# NodeJS async module + redis

Tags: node.js

Im using the `async` model in node along with redis.

My code:

```
async.each(data, function(n, done) {
        redisClient.LLEN("user:" + n + ":active", function(err, numbActive) {
            if(!err) {
                console.log("[CHECKING].... " + n + " NUMB::::: " + numbActive);
                globalNumbActive += numbActive;
                done(globalNumbActive);
            } else {
                done(err, 0);
            }
        });             
}, function(err, globalNumbActive) {
    console.log("GLOBALS --> " + globalNumbActive);
    return callback(globalNumbActive);
});
```

Data above contains:

```
['231', '323', '323']
```

I want to check each of the userIDs in the `user:user_id:active` list, then sum them and return.

Right now the above just grabs the first and then returns.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: start by logging err in your callback

Answer (score 0):

What if the second argument of the main callback is removed? The following snippet works for me.

```
// Assume the two lists have been created in the way below.
// redisClient.lpush('user:231:active', 'John', 'Adam');
// redisClient.lpush('user:323:active', 'Sam');

var data = ['231', '323', '323'];
var globalNumActive = 0;
async.each(data, function(n, callback) {
    redisClient.llen('user:' + n + ':active', function(err, numActive) {
        if (!err) {
            globalNumActive += numActive;
            console.log('user id: ' + n + '\tactive #: ' + numActive + '\ttotal active #: ' + globalNumActive);
            callback(null);
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log('total active #: ' + globalNumActive);
});
```

The output is

```
user id: 231    active #: 2    total active #: 2
user id: 323    active #: 1    total active #: 3
user id: 323    active #: 1    total active #: 4
total active #: 4
```